# Emacs daemon major mode startup

Tags: init-file, emacsclient

I load multiple daemons service at startup with systemd.
The purpose of this is to have each one for different applications, one for C coding, one for Ocaml, one for Org...

I have a configuration file for each client which is passed to `-e` with `load-file` when running the daemon.
I want to set the dedault major mode of the scratch buffer for each one of them, so in the config file I have, for the ocaml config as example :

```
 (setq initial-major-mode 'tuareg-mode)
 (setq initial-scratch-message "\
 (* This buffer is for notes you don't want to save, and for OCaml code.
 * If you want to create a file, visit that file with C-x C-f,
 * then enter the text in that file's own buffer. *)")
```

The message is written but the major mode is still lisp.

What happens and how I can I fix that ?

Comment: Apparently the scratch buffer already exists by the time the command line arguments are evaluates.  It seems that you have to change this setting in your init file.

Comment: I can kill it and then restart it... I also could start the scratch buffer after load. Is there a proper variable to start the scratch buffer after load ?

Comment: No I don't think so.  Emacs _must_ create an initial buffer early, there's no way to delay that.  Why can't you set the option in your init file?

Comment: Because like I said I want to have different configurations for each daemon, e.g. the daemon called ocaml will have an OCaml scratch buffer, the Perl daemon will have a Perl scratch buffer, etc...
So each daemon needs a different configuration.
Off course, they share the same .init, but they also includes a proper configuration file.
Does that make sense ?

Comment: Well, just pass the daemon name to your Emacs and inspect it in your init file, e.g. set a custom environment variable in the systemd unit file and check the value with `getenv`.

Comment: What would be the variable ? The current starting daemon ?

Comment: Whatever you want; after all you choose the variable.  I'm on mobile currently but I can give you a detailed answer later today.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure about how to do that, I wonder about the concurrency at starts of systemd service...

Comment: How's concurrency an issue here?  I presume you have separate unit files for each daemon; how could these possibly conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change `initial-major-mode` in a file loaded with `-l`, because by the time it's loaded the initial buffer was already created.

You need to set this variable in your init file.  To create different scratch buffer in different Emacs daemons, pass an environment variable while you start that daemon instance, e.g.

```
$ export MY_EMACS_DAEMON="ocaml"
$ emacs --daemon …
```

In your init file inspect the value of the variable and set `initial-major-mode` accordingly, e.g.

```
(when (string= (getenv "MY_EMACS_DAEMON") "ocaml")
  (setq initial-buffer-choice 'tuareg-mode))
```

To set this variable in a systemd unit file use the [`Environment=`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=) option, as in:

```
Environment=MY_EMACS_DAEMON=tuareg
```

Comment: Actually I don't know why but this cause the service fails to start.
I have added the Environment in systemd, theres another Environment for ssh but I've put it in two lines like how it should be.
My wm login take about 4sec instead of 0s and then I can't start clients.
I have tried both executing the correct mode and  loading the config file when the environment is right but it fails at some points and I have no clue why...
I should mention that the daemons are running. 
I have encountered the same kind of behaviour when there was some bad lisp in my .init but I have checked it like 10 times.

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto I don't know, you should probably ask a separate question on superuser about your systemd configuration.  It's long since I used Linux, and I'm afraid I can't help you with this strange problem.

Comment: The line `(when (string= (getenv "MY_EMACS_DAEMON") "ocaml")
  (setq initial-buffer-choice 'tuareg-mode))` in the .emacs cause the service failing to start.
I have tried to replace it with something a simple `(when (string= (getenv "MY_EMACS_DAEMON") "ocaml")
  (message "hello ocaml !")` and it fails too.
I guess I need another trick if there is one but thank you.
Having separate config is a bit trickier than I expected.

Comment: That would happen when the variable isn't set.  Try to replace `string=` with `equal`, and make sure that the variable is properly exported, i.e. inspect `process-environment` in your daemon instance.

Comment: Ok finally I did some good testing and I have found the source of problems, both functions `string=` and `equal` work well, in fact it's `(setq initial-major-mode 'tuareg-mode)` who fails with the damon. It works without the daemon but fails with it... I'm stuck.

Comment: The failure come from `error "utop-setup-ocaml-buffer' is deprecated, you need to replace it by utop-minor-mode'`. The service doesn't start for the tiniest error so I have two choice, correct the errors or ignore the ones like that. How can I correct this error ?
I have tried to ignore it with the macro from http://blog.nguyenvq.com/blog/2011/06/30/ignore-errors-when-executing-a-command-in-emacs-with-condition-case/ but the service still doesn't run, so correcting the error seems to be the only solution.

Comment: You should fix your utop setup according to this error message.  If you have problems with that please ask a separate question

Comment: I fixed it !
The problem cames from utop binding to tuareg, I copied the settings from wikiemacs about tuareg installation but they don't work for me !

Now I know that if I have a problem starting an emacs daemon service, it's surely an elisp problem. The positive from it is that I must have clean code in my emacs !

Comment: Don't copy from random places in the Internet. Instead, read the documentation of the packages you're using.